# Getting a few folders up in getJSON

Tags: jquery

So I have checked the *`window.location.pathname`* and that is `/scheduling/events/add/124`.

From this I need to get to `/scheduling/countries/getCountries` in getJSON function, but I just cannot seem to get there.

It has to be something simple, but help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are complete different routing, why you want to get one from another?

Comment: Because I need to call a function in the same framework, to get json response inside the events/add.

Comment: could u please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried: `../../../countries/getCountries` ?

In theory this should go up 3 levels so you have the common `scheduling` root than go down on the right path.

Comment: Even though i just got it to work this way ../../../../scheduling/countries/getCountries.
Any idea for why it does not work the way you suggested?

Comment: Well, I have no idea. How about `/../../../countries/getCountries`? Should be the same as the previous proposal but...who knows.